# Make transparent regions using a mask

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a batch of images that need a transparent background. I am able to create a black/white mask of the lighter and darker regions and want to use this mask to keep the pixels, which are white in the mask unchanged and set all pixel to transparent, which are black. The best outcome so far I got with

```
convert $FILE -rotate "-90<" $ROTATED
convert $ROTATED \
  +dither \
  -colors 2 \
  -fill black \
  -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' \
  -flop \
  -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' \
  -flop \
  -white-threshold 0 \
  $MASK
convert $ROTATED -mask $MASK -compose copy-opacity -composite $OUT
```

But the last command just "ghosts" the whole image. How can I "cut out" the black pixels and keep the white pixels unchanged?

This is what I get so far.

[image: Origin image]
[image: Ghost result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to remove the "-mask" from your command line leaving your mask image (and add -alpha off). So the following works fine for me in ImageMagick 6.

Input:

[image]

```
convert star.png \
+dither \
-colors 2 \
-fill black \
-draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' \
-flop \
-draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' \
-flop \
-white-threshold 0 \
mask.png
convert star.png mask.png -alpha off -compose copy-opacity -composite out.png
```

Mask:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Download the result to see that the background is fully transparent.

If using Imagemagick 7, then change `convert` to `magick`

**ADDITION**

Here is one way to do that with MPR. Note the +swap.

```
convert star.png \
-write mpr:star \
+dither \
-colors 2 \
-fill black \
-draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' \
-flop \
-draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' \
-flop \
-white-threshold 0 \
mpr:star \
+swap \
-alpha off \
-compose copy-opacity -composite \
out.png
```

You can also do it with a clone and parentheses.

```
convert star.png \
\( +clone  \
+dither \
-colors 2 \
-fill black \
-draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' \
-flop \
-draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' \
-flop \
-white-threshold 0 \) \
-alpha off \
-compose copy-opacity -composite \
out.png
```

I get the same result as above.

Comment: As it turned out, there seems to be a problem when I use MPR for the mask image. By using other formats, the result is not ghosted.

Comment: OK, getting to it. If the mask is png it works, with the mask being MPR or HEIC I get the ghosted image.

Comment: How are you using MPR. I know little about HEIC except it is still being developed in ImageMagick. So the version you have may have bugs. But proper use of MPR should work. Please show code you use for MPR and I can likely correct it. MPR has to be saved in memory before being used later in the command line. It does not work from one command line to another.

Comment: I have posted an ADDITION in my answer to show how to use MPR.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes things clean. So MPR is no issue here. I tried `convert image.HEIC image.mpr` but as you state it is not gonna work this way.